# Bash while loop to read line upto ;

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a text file like

```
line2
line3;
line4
line5
line6
line7;
```

I need a loop to read the line till **;** on each loop.
on the first loop read up to line3; and on the second loop up to line7; and so on.
no need to merge the lines into a single one

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.  What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider telling `read` to stop on `;` instead of on newlines, and instead to use newlines to delimit individual input items (when using `-a` to read into an array, this makes each line an array element).

[When given your input](https://ideone.com/ppQYab),

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r -d ';' -a lines; do
  echo "Read group of lines:"
  printf ' - %s\n' "${lines[@]};"
done
```

...emits as output:

```
Read group of lines:
 - line2
 - line3;
Read group of lines:
 - line4
 - line5
 - line6
 - line7;
```

You can, if you choose, replace the printf with something like `for line in "${lines[@]}"; do` to create an inner loop to operate on lines within a group one-by-one.

Comment: No need to omit the ; I need that.

Comment: Make it `"${lines[@]};"`, then, to re-add a `;` on output.

Comment: @NikhilSasi, ...btw, one case I _didn't_ take care to handle here is the situation where there's extra content after the last semicolon. Is that able to happen in your use case?

Comment: Perfect, it is working.
a dash - is appearing on each line, I have updated `printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]};"` like this.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the dash is intentional; I put it there to show that we're able to process the line; the expectation is that you will replace printf with your own logic.

Comment: BTW, see https://ideone.com/qjQYzY for an example showing support for files with trailing content after the last semicolon.

Comment: No @charles, no content after the semicolon

Comment: now it prints all line at once, is there any way to print one line at a time?
I need to do something on each line.

Comment: @NikhilSasi, I already told you how to do that. `for line in "${lines[@]};"; do` -- as described in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @NikhilSasi, ...that said, if you just need to operate line-by-line but know when you reach a `;`, that seems like something a normal `while IFS= read -r line; do` loop could handle if you just handle `if [[ $line = *";" ]]; then` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops: one to continue until the end of the file, and an inner loop to read individual lines until you find one that ends with a `;`.

For example,

```
while :; do
    lines=()
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        lines+=( "$line" )
        if [[ $line = *; ]]; then
            break
        fi
    done
    if (( ${#lines[@]} == 0 )); then
        # The previous loop didn't add anything to the array,
        # so the last read must have failed, and we've reached
        # then end of the file
        break
    done
    # do something with $lines
done < file.txt
```

Or, use one loop that pauses to use lines when one ending with a `;` is found:

```
lines=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
    lines+=("$line")
    if [[ $line = *; ]]; then
        # do stuff with lines, then clear the array
        lines=()
    fi
done < file.txt

# If applicable, do something with the last batch of lines
# if the file doesn't end with a ;-terminated line.
```